# String splitting and formatting using python in a sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, split

I have an SQLite database with a column whose entries are a string of the following form "A-B-C" where A, B, C have variable length and are delimited by the "-" character.

In particular, A should be 1 or 2 characters, B 1-4 characters and C 1-5 characters but they may be even longer for some unknown reason.

I tried to split these characters the following way:

- A column where I would have the A substring
- Another one where I'd have the B substring
- Last one where I'd have the C substring.

However, since SQLite doesn't support string splitting and my efforts at hacking with `substr()` and different positioning ended up with a lot of confusion.

I'm trying to do this in python now. However I'm quite new to this, and while I was able to connect to the database and commit statements this way, I'm not quite sure how to go about doing what I want. I saw the `str.rsplit()` function but I'm not exactly sure how to mix between both languages.

For instance, I should probably write

```
c = conn.execute(
       UPDATE database SET Column_1 = 
                 def First(
                    str.rsplit(Column), 1) 
                        SELECT Column FROM database )
```

with the `First` function returning the first value of the split string from `Column`, and so on for `Column_2` and `Column_3`.

Once I have that I need to format each of column_1, column_2 and column_3 so that they each have at least 2, 4 and 5 characters each by adjoining zeroes to the left of the characters in the columns, depending on the length of the resulting string.

EDIT:

I'm having quite a few problems updating the database:

The following yields the first value:

```
with con: cur = con.cursor() cur.execute('SELECT Column1 FROM MainTable') row = cur.fetchone() for line in row: a, b, c= line.split('-') print (b);
```

A slight modification using:

`while True: 
cur.fetchone()== None then Break`

yields all values. 
However, I can get it to update the database for a given column say Col2, because it has a ton of syntax errors related to mixing python and SQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` method to split a string:

```
data = [
    'ab-de-ghijk',
    'a-bcde-fghi',
]
for string in data:
    a, b, c = string.split('-')
    print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: How do I get the data? Data = fetchall(column_name) ?

Comment: In my example I showed how to split the string in python.  It makes no assumptions about where the data came from or where/how you might want to store it.  So take the string out of the DB however you would like, and then split it using the example code.

Comment: Can you please look at my question about how to update a given column? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @JoséUrriola, I found your question unclear in that regard.  I suggest formulating an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example and posting a new targeted question showing exactly where your code is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have posted the following new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074966/how-to-update-a-column-in-sqlite-using-pysqlite-where-i-first-needed-to-obtain-a