# How to update a column in SQLite using pysqlite where I first needed to obtain a conditional value from other data in my table?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

So, I have the following issue when updating my database:

I have a column in my table that I need to split in three essentially and so I have the following code:

```
with con:
  cur = con.cursor()
  cur.execute('SELECT Column1 FROM MainTable')
  while True row = cur.fetchone() 
    if row == None:
      break 
for line in row: a, b, c= line.split('-') 
  print (b);
```

which gives me the values of the second column for instance. 
However, I need to UPDATE that second column with those values and for this I have tried adding the following at the bottom:

```
cur.execute('UPDATE MainTable SET Col_2 = ?' WHERE Id = 1, (row, Id))

con.commit()
```

However, for some reason this isn't running well.

Comment: Probably unrelated - you are missing a where clause in your update. please check

Comment: I started having a go at editing the long line of code and then realised I don't know what is going on here: `while True cur.fetchone == None Break;`. Please format your code correctly so that it's possible to see an accurate representation; that happens to precede the line that you find isn't working.

Comment: Hello, I have edited a bit because you're right and the first line of code was wrong.

Comment: But there are no line breaks in your code or any indentation to see what code belongs in what block. You can't have a horizontal line of code like that.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll see if I can edit that because that's not how it really looks.

Comment: That code is still wrong. Just use copy/paste.

Comment: @GurV I added that clause but I'm not exactly sure giving it an Id works like I want it to. Thx!

Comment: @CL is it actually wrong? this is what I had written down. I'm sure the following works for just one though : with con: cur = con.cursor() cur.execute('SELECT Column1 FROM MainTable') row = cur.fetchone() for line in row : a, b, c = line.split('-') print (b);

Comment: `cur.execute('UPDATE MainTable SET Col_2 = ?' WHERE Id = 1, (row, Id))` this is very wrong. Can you confirm now that your code in the question is an **accurate** reflection of what you have?

Comment: I know that last bit of code is wrong. That's what I had tried to update and failed to. I think the first piece of code is correct though, at least it's what I have written down in paper from when I ran it on the database and it returned the values fine(maybe I wrote some of it down erroneously).

Comment: I think your final point is true. This has lots of syntax errors and probably indentation mistakes (`for line in row:`, and ignoring the rest of that line, does not work in the way the previous `while` loop, also invalid syntax, would imply). This is unanswerable as it is. Unless you can copy/paste from your existing code or are proficient in creating valid syntax, nobody can help you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

To update a specific row, you need a way to identify the row.
You appear to have an "ID" column, so read that together with the string you want split.

SQL statements have *nothing* to do with Python; what you do in Python is to construct an SQL string that you then give to the database to execute. (Using `?`-style parameters avoids string formatting problems and SQL injection attacks; always use them for values.)

```
cur.execute('SELECT ID, Column1 FROM MainTable')
for id, col1 in cur.fetchall():
    a, b, c = col1.split('-')
    cur.execute('UPDATE MainTable SET ColA = ?, ColB = ?, ColC = ? WHERE ID = ?',
                [a, b, c, id])
con.commit()
```